# Python: Saving numbers error when saved as string

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with my code, here:

```
correct = 0

grade_book = {}
File = open('Test.txt', 'r')
for line in File:
     name, scores = line.split(':')
     grade_book[name] = scores.strip()
File.close()
print(grade_book)

name = input("Name: ")
if name in grade_book.keys():
    grade_book[name] += ',' + correct
else:
    grade_book[name] = correct

File = open('Test.txt', 'w')
for name, scores in grade_book.items():
    out_line = str(name) + ':' + str(scores) + "\n"
    File.write(out_line)

File.close()
```

The problem is that it gives an error stating:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

This happens in the program when it tries to save 'correct' to an existing name in the file. I've tried to fix the problem with the following:

```
    name = input("Name: ")
if name in grade_book.keys():
    grade_book[name] += ',' + str(correct)
else:
    grade_book[name] = correct
```

But the problem with this is that the number printed to file is always 0, despite 'correct' being assigned to numbers more than 0, such as 8. On the other hand it doesent give an error like before, just the problem above.

Any solutions to this?

> Yeah, Im probably missing something really obvious here.

Code for 'correct':

```
def mainLoop():
    global count
    global correct
    Num1 = randint(1, 10)
    Num2 = randint(1,10)
    Operand= randint(1,3)

    if Operand == 1:
        question = str(Num1) + " + " + str(Num2) + " = "
        answer = Num1 + Num2
    elif Operand == 2:
        question = str(Num1) + " - " + str(Num2) +" = "
        answer = Num1 - Num2
    else:
        question = str(Num1) + " x " + str(Num2) + " = "
        answer = Num1 * Num2

    userAnswer = int(input(question))
    if userAnswer == answer:
        correct += 1
```

Guess I'll post the whole code for reference:

```
from random import randint
import time
count = 0
correct = 0

def mainLoop():
   global count
   global correct
   Num1 = randint(1, 10)
   Num2 = randint(1,10)
   Operand= randint(1,3)

   if Operand == 1:
       question = str(Num1) + " + " + str(Num2) + " = "
        answer = Num1 + Num2
   elif Operand == 2:
       question = str(Num1) + " - " + str(Num2) +" = "
       answer = Num1 - Num2
   else:
       question = str(Num1) + " x " + str(Num2) + " = "
       answer = Num1 * Num2

 userAnswer = int(input(question))
 if userAnswer == answer:
  correct += 1



grade_book = {}
File = open('Test.txt', 'r')
for line in File:
    name, scores = line.split(':')
   grade_book[name] = scores.strip()
File.close()
print(grade_book)

name = input("Name: ")
if name in grade_book.keys():
   grade_book[name] += ',' + str(correct)
else:
   grade_book[name] = str(correct)

File = open('Test.txt', 'w')
for name, scores in grade_book.items():
    out_line = str(name) + ':' + str(scores) + "\n"
    File.write(out_line)

File.close()

 while count < 10:
    mainLoop()
    count += 1
```

> Did the indends fast, may be wrong

Text File Exmple:

`Test:1,5
John:1,0`

Comment: What is the expected functionality?

Comment: I see `correct = 0` but no other assignments to `correct`. Why do you think it should be greater than 0?

Comment: what's the data format in 'test.txt'?

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: You are not doing anything with "correct". It is always 0. What are you trying to do with "correct"?

Comment: In your OP when you did str(correct). This is correct if you are looking to concatenate strings. However, based on my previous comment, you aren't doing anything to change the value of correct.

Comment: Can you give some input output?????

Comment: Added the code which controls 'correct'

Comment: In the code excerpt at the top you don't actually call `mainLoop` so the value of `correct` will still be 0. If your actual code does call `mainLoop` it may be calling it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `mainLoop` after writing the scores to your file, so the file will not contain the correct scores. Just move the code that asks the questions 10 times (`while count < 10` etc.) to above the code that writes the scores to the `grade_book` (`if name in grade_book.keys():` etc.).

You may find it helpful to avoid using global variables. Instead, you could have a question function that returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the user responds correctly or not, and then we just use `sum` to count up the right and wrong responses.

```
from random import randint
import time

def question():
   a = randint(1, 10)
   b = randint(1,10)
   operand= randint(1,3)

   if operand == 1:
       sign = '+'
       answer = a + b
   elif operand == 2:
       sign = '-'
       answer = a - b
   else:
       sign = 'x'
       answer = a * b

   user_answer = int(input('{} {} {} = '.format(a, sign, b)))
   return user_answer == answer # returns True if correct, False if not

grade_book = {}
with open('Test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, scores = line.split(':')
        grade_book[name] = scores.strip()
print(grade_book)

name = input("Name: ")

# Ask a question 10 times and sum up the correct responses
# (This works because sum counts True as 1 and False as 0)
correct = sum(question() for _ in range(10)) 

if name in grade_book.keys():
   grade_book[name] += ',' + str(correct)
else:
   grade_book[name] = str(correct)

with open('Test.txt', 'w') as file:
    for name, scores in grade_book.items():
        file.write('{}:{}\n'.format(name, scores))
```

Comment: This works apart from one thing, after the first score being saved its saving all the others on the same line as the first which causes an error?

Comment: @Csarg edited to add `\n` in the `file.write`, which should fix this.

Comment: I figured this out right before you posted, but thanks alot. Ticked this as my final answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In `grade_book[name] = correct` You assign integer value `correct`. So it should be:

```
name = input("Name: ")
if name in grade_book.keys():
    grade_book[name] += ',' + str(correct)
else:
    grade_book[name] = str(correct)
```

And You are not doing anything with "correct". It is always 0.